Whenever changes in Google Sheet, I'd like to get Messages in Slack
I made a web page with Softr. If my customers encode something in the web page, it will be encoded in Google sheet.
Whenever there are changes in google sheet, I'd like to get the messages in Slack.
I made it w/ Apps Script and could get messages in Slack but it does NOT SHOW VALUES in the cells as below.
Slack Message :
Sheet: Sheet1, Cell: A130:F130, New Value:
If you know about this, please help me how I can change this coding.
const WEBHOOK_URL = *'I encoded here the webhookurl of my slack channel'*; // 여기에 생성한 Webhook URL을 입력하세요.

function sendSlackNotification(sheetName, cell, value) {
  var message = `Sheet: ${sheetName}, Cell: ${cell}, New Value: ${value}`;

  Logger.log(message); // 디버깅을 위해 로그에 기록

  // 슬랙에 알림 보내기
  var payload = {
    text: message
  };

  var options = {
    method: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(WEBHOOK_URL, options);
}

function onChange(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();

  // 변경된 범위를 가져오기 위해 마지막 편집 시간을 이용
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var range = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, lastColumn);
  var cell = range.getA1Notation();
  var value = range.getValue();

  sendSlackNotification(sheetName, cell, value);
}


I don't know what the value of the cell in column A of row 130 is, but for example, what if you try the following?
from:
  // 변경된 범위를 가져오기 위해 마지막 편집 시간을 이용
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var range = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, lastColumn);
  var cell = range.getA1Notation();
  var value = range.getValue();

Displays the entire value for one line.
And insert timeStamp into Column A.
to:
  // 변경된 범위를 가져오기 위해 마지막 편집 시간을 이용
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var range = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, lastColumn);
  range.getCell(1, 1).setValue(new Date()); // ←
  var cell = range.getA1Notation();
  var value = range.getValues()[0]; // ←


Thank you so much  It is working now!
I have one more questions, if this is okay.
Is it possible to add Timestamp, which is similar in Google form?
Google form creates Timestamp automatically in A column of google sheet whenever users encode it.
I would like to insert in A col. for Timestamp function, using Apps script.
Thank you.

var range = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, lastColumn);
→
var range = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, lastColumn);
range.getCell(1, 1).setValue(new Date());

@Kiwijuice Follow up questions should be posted as a new question... don't use comments for that.
